# Clue of origin with a connection to mythology

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking, story, knowledge, history

Assume that you were privileged and invited to attend a party arranged during a pre-historic time. It was hosted by none other than Adam (the mythological man as per religious beliefs), the first man, who was created by the god. It was an all-male party.

You accepted the invitation and attended the party, which was attended by a large number of people.

However, in the party you are not sure who was the host (that is, Adam) and your task is to identify him, though you have observed that all of the attendees are semi-clad/semi-naked (of course, as expected, as the time was pre-historic).

You thought for a moment and got a means to identify who Adam was.

Question is - **what was the means for you to identify who Adam was?**

Note: This is a fictional question and not intended to hurt anyone's feelings/sentiments in any manner whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adam is the man who has

> no belly button,

because

> as he was the first person to be created, he wasn't born from a mother with an umbilical cord.

Comment: Well, that was too quick. Correct.

Comment: But see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omphalos_(book)...

Comment: [Arguably one of the most famous depictions of Adam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Creation_of_Adam), however, shows him with a belly-button. And who wants to argue with the genius of Michelangelo?

Comment: I guess you'd be doing a lot of navel-gazing at this party ...

Answer (score 8):

could u just like... yell 'adam'

or offer round some apples and see who started crying

alternatively, count their ribs

Comment: Interested in knowing how the third option is of some help.

Comment: am pretty sure that in the bible, eve was created from one of adam's ribs, so he would have one less rib than everyone else there? unless they all had rib-friends too, but that feels unlikely

Comment: okay i googled it and it's genesis 2:18-24. i had quite the christian upbringing and that bit stuck in my head i guess!

Comment: Got it @issy though not sure...If a rib bone was sacrificed to create Eve / or keeping it in tact. Another case of use of lateral thinking. +1.

Answer (score 3):

We can identify Adams easily

> The person having the longest hair would be Adams, as it was
>   prehistoric time razors were not invented. And as being the first
>   human/male he must have the longest hair.
>
> Unless he had a baldness disease. (I doubt!)

Comment: Good attempt. Though means selected is subjective and hence not definitive.

Comment: Razors weren't invented yet, but *sharp things* in general were.

Comment: Well it was worth a try...

Answer (score 2):

I think he is the:

> Oldest man at the party

giving that:

> he is the first man, and that he is still alive (hosting this party). Any other man must be at least 1 generation younger than him and that's something very noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder

> The guy who is giving fatherly advice to everyone,like ..not to use alcohol,dont trust snakes..kinda stuff..

Answer (score 0):

Show him a snake and see if he asks

> But where are its legs?